# Find closest value in a vector with binary search

Tags: r

As a silly toy example, suppose

```
x=4.5
w=c(1,2,4,6,7)
```

I wonder if there is a simple R function that finds the index of the closest match to `x` in `w`.  So if `foo` is that function, `foo(w,x)` would return `3`.  The function `match` is the right idea, but seems to apply only for exact matches.

Solutions [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Find-the-closest-value-in-a-list-or-matrix-td838131.html) (e.g. `which.min(abs(w - x))`, `which(abs(w-x)==min(abs(w-x)))`, etc.) are all `O(n)` instead of `log(n)` (I'm assuming that `w` is already sorted).

Comment: `fuzzyjoin` could be helpful in setting explicit criteria for and finding inexact matches according to the match that has the best score

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `data.table` to do a binary search:

```
dt = data.table(w, val = w) # you'll see why val is needed in a sec
setattr(dt, "sorted", "w")  # let data.table know that w is sorted
```

Note that if the column `w` isn't already sorted, then you'll have to use `setkey(dt, w)` instead of `setattr(.)`.

```
# binary search and "roll" to the nearest neighbour
dt[J(x), roll = "nearest"]
#     w val
#1: 4.5   4
```

In the final expression the `val` column will have the you're looking for.

```
# or to get the index as Josh points out
# (and then you don't need the val column):
dt[J(x), .I, roll = "nearest", by = .EACHI]
#     w .I
#1: 4.5  3

# or to get the index alone
dt[J(x), roll = "nearest", which = TRUE]
#[1] 3
```

Comment: This must be 99% of the way to the answer.  In the end, I want `3`, the index of `4` in `w`.

Comment: I had a similar thought, but given that the OP wants the vector's index, would have done: `dt = data.table(w, key="w"); dt[J(x), .I,roll = "nearest"][[2]]`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien fair enough, I didn't read OP too carefully :), but don't use the key argument - that will force a resort

Comment: @eddi, I don't think it's specified that the vector is *always* sorted. And even if it is, I think `setkey` checks for `is.sorted(.)` before sorting.

Comment: @Arun -- OP does mention that the vector can be assumed sorted, but I was thinking along the lines of your second sentence. Any way to mark the data.table as already sorted by a column without actually resorting it?

Comment: @Arun `is.sorted` is `O(n)` when the vector is sorted and so takes a very long time.

Comment: @eddi: `x <- 1:1e7; system.time(is.unsorted(x))` (0.057 seconds).

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, I did miss the last line. Thanks. It's the way eddi has done it. `setkey` looks for `attribute` "sorted". But, even if it's sorted, it still checks to make sure it is sorted, iirc (as in some cases, you may have noticed the warning "the key was set, but not properly.. so setting again.."

Comment: @Arun -- So doing `attributes(dt) <- c(attributes(dt), sorted="w")` is not only hacky but ineffective! Sounds like good software design on the part of the **data.table** team.

Comment: @Arun exactly ;) when you live in a world where you want to use a binary search for this problem, it's likely you also live in a world where that's 57 milliseconds more than 0.

Comment: @Arun what about it? it *is* `O(n)` - try increasing/decreasing size of `x` - to check if something is sorted you *have to* go through the entire thing

Comment: @Arun btw I just timed `setkey` and it's much slower than `is.unsorted` - haven't looked at the code yet but it does seem like it's sorting a sorted vector

Comment: Hmm, it does seem like `is.unsorted` is not called unless the "attribute" is set. I wonder why.. I think there's speedup possible here. Will check.

Comment: One issue maybe with `NA` values though.

Comment: What is `J` in `J(x)` in `dt[J(x), roll = "nearest"]`?

Comment: @ConnerM. it's a shortcut for `data.table`. Nowadays you can also use `.` instead of `J`.

Comment: FWIW, if there are repeat values in the w vector, the above solution will give the index of the rightmost solution. To get the leftmost solution, add in `mult='first'`, so the full line would be: dt[J(x), roll = "nearest", which = TRUE, mult='first']

Answer (score 46):

```
R>findInterval(4.5, c(1,2,4,5,6))
[1] 3
```

will do that with price-is-right matching (closest without going over).

Comment: findInterval {base}
Find Interval Numbers or Indices

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html

Comment: To get the nearest element using this approach you can do search in intervals from mid points between adjacent target points: `w[findInterval(x, (w[-length(w)] + w[-1]) / 2) + 1]`

Comment: @Gedrox That should work, but its O(n) instead of O(log n) because of  the midpoint calculation.

Comment: @NealFultz, you're right. For performance simple "if" check for the distance to the next point is enough. `if (res == 0 || (res != length(w) && w[res + 1] - x < x - w[res])) res <- res + 1`

Answer (score 8):

See `match.closest()` from the MALDIquant package:

```
> library(MALDIquant)
> match.closest(x, w)
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NearestValueSearch = function(x, w){
  ## A simple binary search algo
  ## Assume the w vector is sorted so we can use binary search
  left = 1
  right = length(w)
  while(right - left > 1){
    middle = floor((left + right) / 2)
    if(x < w[middle]){
      right = middle
    }
    else{
      left = middle
    }
  }
  if(abs(x - w[right]) < abs(x - w[left])){
    return(right)
  }
  else{
    return(left)
  }
}


x = 4.5
w = c(1,2,4,6,7)
NearestValueSearch(x, w) # return 3
```

Comment: This algorithm is extremely fast compared to the other proposals: 
`w = cumsum(abs(rnorm(100000)))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(NearestValueSearch(777,w))   # 12 µs
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(which.min(abs(w-777)))    # 300 µs
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(findInterval(777,w))   # 140 µs `

Comment: @egus it is however much slower than `findInterval` if you are searching for many values (`NearsestValueSearch` would require wrapping in `sapply`) and in contrast to the other solutions will *silently* fail, when the assumptions are not met.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = 4.5
w = c(1,2,4,6,7)

closestLoc = which(min(abs(w-x)))
closestVal = w[which(min(abs(w-x)))]

# On my phone- please pardon typos
```

If your vector is lengthy, try a 2-step approach:

```
x = 4.5
w = c(1,2,4,6,7)

sdev = sapply(w,function(v,x) abs(v-x), x = x)
closestLoc = which(min(sdev))
```

for maddeningly long vectors (millions of rows!, warning- this will actually be slower for data which is not very, very, very large.)

```
require(doMC)
registerDoMC()

closestLoc = which(min(foreach(i = w) %dopar% {
   abs(i-x)
}))
```

This example is just to give you a basic idea of leveraging parallel processing when you have huge data. Note, I do not recommend you use it for simple & fast functions like abs().

Comment: Just saw. data.table is the way to go!

Answer (score 3):

To do this on character vectors, Martin Morgan suggested this function on [R-help](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/General-binary-search-td3426478.html):

```
bsearch7 <-
     function(val, tab, L=1L, H=length(tab))
{
     b <- cbind(L=rep(L, length(val)), H=rep(H, length(val)))
     i0 <- seq_along(val)
     repeat {
         updt <- M <- b[i0,"L"] + (b[i0,"H"] - b[i0,"L"]) %/% 2L
         tabM <- tab[M]
         val0 <- val[i0]
         i <- tabM < val0
         updt[i] <- M[i] + 1L
         i <- tabM > val0
         updt[i] <- M[i] - 1L
         b[i0 + i * length(val)] <- updt
         i0 <- which(b[i0, "H"] >= b[i0, "L"])
         if (!length(i0)) break;
     }
     b[,"L"] - 1L
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @neal-fultz answer, here is a simple function that uses `findInterval()`:

```r
get_closest_index <- function(x, vec){
  # vec must be sorted
  iv <- findInterval(x, vec)
  dist_left <- x - vec[ifelse(iv == 0, NA, iv)]
  dist_right <- vec[iv + 1] - x
  ifelse(! is.na(dist_left) & (is.na(dist_right) | dist_left < dist_right), iv, iv + 1)
}
values <- c(-15, -0.01, 3.1, 6, 10, 100)
grid <- c(-2, -0.1, 0.1, 3, 7)
get_closest_index(values, grid)
#> [1] 1 2 4 5 5 5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score -2):

You can always implement custom binary search algorithm to find the closest value. Alternately, you can leverage standard implementation of libc bsearch(). You can use other binary search implementations as well, but it does not change the fact that you have to implement the comparing function carefully to find the closest element in array. The issue with standard binary search implementation is that it is meant for **exact comparison**. That means your *improvised* comparing function needs  to do some kind of **exactification** to figure out if an element in array is close-enough. To achieve it, the comparing function needs to have awareness of other elements in the array, especially following aspects:

- position of the current element (one which is being compared with the
  key).
- the distance with key and how it compares with neighbors    (previous
  or next element).

To provide this extra knowledge in comparing function, the key needs to be packaged with additional information (not just the key value). Once the comparing function have awareness on these aspects, it can figure out if the *element itself* is closest. When it knows that it is the closest, it returns "match".

The the following C code finds the closest value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct key {
        int key_val;
        int *array_head;
        int array_size;
};

int compar(const void *k, const void *e) {
        struct key *key = (struct key*)k;
        int *elem = (int*)e;
        int *arr_first = key->array_head;
        int *arr_last = key->array_head + key->array_size -1;
        int kv = key->key_val;
        int dist_left;
        int dist_right;

        if (kv == *elem) {
                /* easy case: if both same, got to be closest */
                return 0;
        } else if (key->array_size == 1) {
                /* easy case: only element got to be closest */
                return 0;
        } else if (elem == arr_first) {
                /* element is the first in array */
                if (kv < *elem) {
                        /* if keyval is less the first element then
                         * first elem is closest.
                         */
                        return 0;
                } else {
                        /* check distance between first and 2nd elem.
                         * if distance with first elem is smaller, it is closest.
                         */
                        dist_left = kv - *elem;
                        dist_right = *(elem+1) - kv;
                        return (dist_left <= dist_right) ? 0:1;
                }
        } else if (elem == arr_last) {
                /* element is the last in array */
                if (kv > *elem) {
                        /* if keyval is larger than the last element then
                         * last elem is closest.
                         */
                        return 0;
                } else {
                        /* check distance between last and last-but-one.
                         * if distance with last elem is smaller, it is closest.
                         */
                        dist_left = kv - *(elem-1);
                        dist_right = *elem - kv;
                        return (dist_right <= dist_left) ? 0:-1;
                }
        }

        /* condition for remaining cases (other cases are handled already):
         * - elem is neither first or last in the array
         * - array has atleast three elements.
         */

        if (kv < *elem) {
                /* keyval is smaller than elem */

                if (kv <= *(elem -1)) {
                        /* keyval is smaller than previous (of "elem") too.
                         * hence, elem cannot be closest.
                         */
                        return -1;
                } else {
                        /* check distance between elem and elem-prev.
                         * if distance with elem is smaller, it is closest.
                         */
                        dist_left = kv - *(elem -1);
                        dist_right = *elem - kv;
                        return (dist_right <= dist_left) ? 0:-1;
                }
        }

        /* remaining case: (keyval > *elem) */

        if (kv >= *(elem+1)) {
                /* keyval is larger than next (of "elem") too.
                 * hence, elem cannot be closest.
                 */
                return 1;
        }

        /* check distance between elem and elem-next.
         * if distance with elem is smaller, it is closest.
         */
        dist_right = *(elem+1) - kv;
        dist_left = kv - *elem;
        return (dist_left <= dist_right) ? 0:1;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70};
        int *found;
        struct key k;

        if (argc < 2) {
                return 1;
        }

        k.key_val = atoi(argv[1]);
        k.array_head = arr;
        k.array_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);

        found = (int*)bsearch(&k, arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int), sizeof(int),
                compar);

        if(found) {
                printf("found closest: %d\n", *found);
        } else {
                printf("closest not found. absurd! \n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Needless to say that bsearch() in above example should never fail (unless the array size is zero).

If you implement your own custom binary search, essentially you have to embed same comparing logic in the main body of binary search code (instead of having this logic in comparing function in above example).

Comment: In addition, there are other tricks can be played as well. One of the property of binary search (or other searches as well) is that when search fails, the last comparison fails within the "proximity" of the key. For example, if the key is larger than the last element of the array, the last failed comparison is going to be with the last element. If key within the the range of array, the last two comparisons are going be with the elements located at the left and right sides of the key. 

If comparison function save distances, you can figure out the closest value even when bsearch() fails.

Comment: That is a C function, not an R function.