# R fastest way to do lookup for vector of strings

Tags: r, sorting, search, lookup

I have a vector of strings `x = c("hello", "world")` and another vector `y = c("hello", "world", "how", "are", "you")`.  I want to see which elements of x are inside y.  For small vector this could easily be done using `x %in% y`.  However I am looking for a more efficient way to do this - normally we would sort y first in `O(n log n)` time, then foreach string inside x we can do lookup in `O(log n)` time.  I am worried that %in% is doing a full pass over y for each x it is looking up.

Is there a way to take advantage of sort and binary search in R?  Or is there a way to build a hashset from y for fast lookup times?

Comment: The `data.table` package implements binary search--see http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf

Comment: Have you don't any benchmarking of your own? Match() (and `%in%`) will build a hash table of it's own for long enough vectors. Are you matching repeatedly against the same values, or is this a one time match that does them all?

Comment: also see package `hash` http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hash/hash.pdf

Comment: This might be helpful - [Find closest value in a vector with binary search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133344/find-closest-value-in-a-vector-with-binary-search)

Comment: The `%chin%` function in `data.table` is supposedly optimized for character vectors

Comment: Indeed, %chin% was the fastest way to search character vectors