# Find index of value in a sorted vector in R

Tags: r, indexof

I have an ordered vector of unique integers in R and I want to find the index of the element closest to but less than or equal to some value. For example, for the vector `4 8 15 16 23 42` and the search value `17`, I would like the function to return `4`, the index of `16`. In Python, I would use
[bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module. Is there anything similar in R?

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133344/find-closest-value-in-a-vector-with-binary-search

Comment: Using rolling joins from data.table package, `data.table(x, key="x")[.(16), roll=-Inf, which=TRUE]`

Comment: `findInterval(17, x)`

Answer (score 7):

Base R provides [`findInterval`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html), which implements a binary search:

```
findInterval(17, c(4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42))
```

---

@Khashaa already mentioned this in a comment.

Comment: Unfortunately `findInterval` appears to be 2-3x slower than simply using `which(non_decreasing_haystack == needle)`

Comment: @zdebruine this probably strongly depends on the size of the `non_decreasing_haystack` and the number of `needle`s. Can you provide an benchmark?

Comment: @zdebruine well, your `which()` solution wouldn't work for this, because none of the values are equal to the target.  You could do `which.min(abs(non_decreasing_haystack - needle))`.