# How to get the row number when using roll=nearest in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to find the nearest value in vector. I found the solution in here using data.table

[Find closest value in a vector with binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133344/find-closest-value-in-a-vector-with-binary-search)

```
x=4.5
w=c(1,2,4,6,7)
dt = data.table(w, val = w) # you'll see why val is needed in a sec
setattr(dt, "sorted", "w")  # let data.table know that w is sorted
dt[J(x), .I, roll = "nearest"]
#     w .I
#1: 4.5  3
```

However I do not get the index form W matrix, it returns 1 which is the location in x. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work for me neither. I'm not sure how it did in previous versions. Though `dt[J(x), val, roll = "nearest"]` will give you the value while `dt[J(x), which = TRUE, roll = "nearest"]` will give you the locaiton

Comment: Perfect. It is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @DavidArenburg make it an answer :)

Comment: @jangorecki it seems actually that adding `by = .EACHI` is the answer but I can't explain why. So probably this is a task for @Arun or @eddi.

Comment: yes, that's it - the answer was written in the olden days when by-without-by was a hidden default; closing as duplicate