# How to find the closest value to your input?

Tags: r

I have  inputs:

```
  Tin=7.02654  ; t=0.1 ;Tou=?;sed=?
```

My question is how to find the value in sed `sed[i]=` that will give `Tou` which has the least difference with Tin or in other words tho closest to my Tin?

What I tried:

```
sed = seq(from = 0, to = 0.7, by=0.001)
for(i in 1:length(sed)) {
  Tou = 5 + t*sed[i]
  find sed[i] = min(abs(Tou-Tin)))
  sed[i] 
}
```

What I shoud put instead of `find sed[i]`?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I would also contribute this suggestion: `which(abs(x-your.number)==min(abs(x-your.number)))` from [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-July/167216.html).

Comment: @Konrad Alternatively, `which.min(abs(x-your.number))` can be used which yields the same index (if no ties are present).

Comment: To avoid duplication, [discussion here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133344/find-closest-value-in-a-vector-with-binary-search) touches on a similar subject and suggests some interesting  approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `which.min` function, which gives the index corresponding to the least value in the given vector. See `?which.min`. Hence, something like this should give what you want:

```
Tin <- 5.04
t <- 0.1
sed <- seq(from = 0, to = 0.7, by = 0.001)

i <- which.min(abs(5 + t*sed - Tin))
#[1] 401

sed[i]
#[1] 0.4
```

Unless I've misunderstood your pseudo code, there seems to be no reason to use a for-loop.

**Edit 2:** 
To answer the comment; it should probably look like this

```
fun <- function(x, d, sed) { # Some complicated function
  return(x*sed^2 + d)
}

myfun <-function(Tin) { 
  sed <- seq(from = 0, to = 0.7, by = 0.001)
  Tou_vec <- fun(x = 1, d = 2, sed = sed) + 5
  i <- which.min(abs(Tou_vec - Tin))
  return(sed[i])
}

myfun(Tin = 5.5)
#[1] 0
```

The function `which.min` expects a `numeric` vector of values and returns the index of the least value. In you code here, you supply a vector of length one, and thus `i` always evaluates to `1`. Also you try to return (or at least print) the (first) value from within the `for`-loop. This doesn't work and an explicit `print` or `return` is needed if you insist. I've attempted to rewrite your `myfun` in the answer. From your example(s), you do not need a `for`-loop.

Comment: @temor It's not right. I've edited my answer.

Comment: You set `t = sed[b] + 0.2` and right after add `5` to make `Tou`. `t` is used nowhere else. This means you could have made `Tou` directly as `sed[b] + 5.2`. Now, you do this for each `b`. Hence you can do it as a vector instead and just make a vector of `Tou`s: i.e. `Tou_vec <- sed + 5.2` (which adds the 5.2 to each element of `sed`). So your `t` and `Tou` variables are somewhat redundant.

Comment: @temor What are `x` and `d` here? If they are constant w.r.t `b`, then `fun` is simply applied to each element of `sed` and 5 is added afterwards--i.e. the code can be vectorized and no for-loop is needed (the `b` is nothing more than bookkeeping on the index). I've edited the answer again. Otherwise, you should update your question (or make a new) where you explain this better.

Answer (score 1):

You can just remember the best result and update it whenever you find Tou with smaller absolute difference from Tin. Like this:

```
Tin = 5.04
t = 0.1

sed = seq(from = 0, to = 0.7, by = 0.001)

bestResult = 5 + t * sed[1]
bestDiff = abs(Tin - bestResult)

for (i in 2:length(sed)) {
  Tou = 5 + t * sed[i]
  diff = abs(Tin - Tou)
  if (diff < bestDiff) {
    bestDiff = diff
    bestResult = Tou
  }
}

bestResult
```

Comment: Thanks .I need to return the value from `sed` that gave the best result`bestResult`. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

One downside to the `which.min` approach is that it returns a number rather than a vector of booleans (Which you can then use `&` or `|` with, and thus can be part of a more complicated filter)

in that case, you want to use the absolute difference as Ardavel said, but there's no reason to track it as part of a loop, this can be done entirely in a data.frame or data.table.

```
Tin=7.02654
t = 0.1
test <- data.frame(sed = seq(from = 0, to = 0.7, by=0.001))
test$Tou <- 5 + t * test$sed
test$sed[abs(test$Tou - Tin) == min(abs(test$Tou - Tin))]
```

Comment: Thanks. What do you think about this function:`myfun <-function(Tin) { sed <- seq(from = 0, to = 0.7, by = 0.001); for(b in 1:length(sed)) { t=sed[b]+0.2; Tou=5+t; i <- which.min(abs(Tou - Tin)) ; sed[i]; }}`      can you update your answer based on this function please?