# R column of ints find nearest value

Tags: r

I have a frame

```
J = data.frame(Entry = c(100, 5, 10, 20, 35))
```

For each record I want to find the nearest value and end up with

```
Entry | nearest
 100  |  35
 5    |  10
 20   |  10
 35   |  20
```

I looked at the data table code [Find closest value in a vector with binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133344/find-closest-value-in-a-vector-with-binary-search)

but because for `Entry` I am trying to find the closest value it just returns the vector that I enter. How can I do this?

Comment: I think the answer you are looking for is in [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-September/359974.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
J <- data.frame(Entry = c(100, 5, 10, 20, 35), 
               X = sapply(J$Entry, function(x){
  temp <- J$Entry[!J$Entry == x]
  temp[which.min(abs(temp - x))]
}))

> J
  Entry  X
1   100 35
2     5 10
3    10  5
4    20 10
5    35 20
```

Like this?