# Matching two very very large vectors with tolerance (fast! but working space sparing)

Tags: r, vector, matching

consider I have two vectors. One is a reference vector/list that includes all values of interest and one samplevector that could contain any possible value. Now I want to find matches of my sample inside the reference list with a certain tolerance which is not fixed and depentent on the comparing values inside the vectors:

```
matches: abs(((referencelist - sample[i])/sample[i])*10^6)) < 0.5
```

rounding both vectors is no option!

for example consider:

```
referencelist <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="value  name
154.00312  A
154.07685  B
154.21452  C
154.49545  D
156.77310  E
156.83991  F
159.02992  G
159.65553  H
159.93843  I")

sample <- c(154.00315, 159.02991, 154.07688, 156.77312)
```

so I get the result:

```
    name value      reference
1    A   154.00315  154.00312
2    G   159.02991  159.02992
3    B   154.07688  154.07685
4    E   156.77312  156.77310
```

what I can do is using e.g. the outer function like

```
myDist <- outer(referencelist, sample, FUN=function(x, y) abs(((x - y)/y)*10^6))
matches <- which(myDist < 0.5, arr.ind=TRUE)
data.frame(name = referencelist$name[matches[, 1]], value=sample[matches[, 2]])
```

or I could use a `for()` loop.

But my special problem is, that the reference vector has around 1*10^12 entries and my sample vector around 1*10^7. so by using outer() I easily destroy all working space limits and by using a `for()` or chained `for()` loop this will took days/weeks to finish.

Has anybody an idea of how to do this fast in R, still precise but working on a computer consuming max. 64 GB RAM?

Thanks for any help!

Best whishes

Comment: Is the reference vector sorted? If so, you can do a bisection method to find the closest number. If not -- sort it! Also, how is it even stored? It is too big to fit in your RAM. Is it a single file or does it span multiple files?

Comment: In the example you give, all values appear to be in a narrow enough range (154, 160). Can we simplify the problem by calculating `(x - y) / 154` instead of `(x - y) / y`?

Comment: @john Coleman: Yes it is sorted ascending. Can you give an example of what is an bisection method? Have not heared it before, I am sry. The reference vector fits into my RAM and then I have around 64 GB free space.

Comment: @aurele I do not know 100% what you mean, but if I understood you correctly then no we cannot, because the range in both vectors goes from around 100 up to 3000.

Comment: I meant to say "binary search". Look at the base R function `findInterval()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your match condition

```
abs(((referencelist - sample[i])/sample[i])*10^6)) < 0.5
```

can be re-written as

```
sample[i] * (1 - eps) < referencelist < sample[i] * (1 + eps)
```

with `eps = 0.5E-6`.

Using this, we can use a *non-equi-join* to find *all* matches (not only the nearest!) in `referencelist` for each `sample`:

```
library(data.table)
options(digits = 10)
eps <- 0.5E-6 # tol * 1E6
setDT(referencelist)[.(value = sample, 
                       lower = sample * (1 - eps), 
                       upper = sample * (1 + eps)), 
                     on = .(ref > lower, ref < upper), .(name, value, reference = x.ref)]
```

which reproduces the expected result:

> ```
>    name     value reference
> 1:    A 154.00315 154.00312
> 2:    G 159.02991 159.02992
> 3:    B 154.07688 154.07685
> 4:    E 156.77312 156.77310
> ```

In response to [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957566/matching-two-very-very-large-vectors-with-tolerance-fast-but-working-space-spa/46960472?noredirect=1#comment80883283_46960472), let's say, we have a modified `referencelist2` with `F = 154.00320` then this will be caught too:

```
setDT(referencelist2)[.(value = sample, 
                       lower = sample * (1 - eps), 
                       upper = sample * (1 + eps)), 
                     on = .(ref > lower, ref < upper), .(name, value, reference = x.ref)]
```

> ```
>    name     value reference
> 1:    A 154.00315 154.00312
> 2:    F 154.00315 154.00320
> 3:    G 159.02991 159.02992
> 4:    B 154.07688 154.07685
> 5:    E 156.77312 156.77310
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Using `data.table` (and copy-pasting from @eddi's [binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20133547/6197649) (also called bisection, cf @John Coleman's comment)):

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(referencelist)
setattr(dt, "sorted", "value")

tol <- 0.5
dt2 <- dt[J(sample), .(.I, ref = value, name), roll = "nearest", by = .EACHI]
dt2[, diff := abs(ref - value) / value * 1e6]
dt2[diff <= tol]

#       value I      ref name       diff
# 1: 154.0032 1 154.0031    A 0.19480121
# 2: 159.0299 7 159.0299    G 0.06288125
# 3: 154.0769 2 154.0769    B 0.19470799
# 4: 156.7731 5 156.7731    E 0.12757289
```

I haven't benchmarked memory usage nor execution time, but `data.table` has the reputation of being very good at both. If it doesn't work for you, say so and maybe I'll try to benchmark things.

Note: my use of `data.table` is quite naive.

And there's a solution using `findInterval` just below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29552922/6197649, but I'd expect it to perform worse (again: would require benchmarks).

Comment: thank you a lot, this sounds very nice. I will test it as soon as possible, but I am sry to say that this might take some hours/days because of the size of the vectors. Back soon and thanks again!

Comment: just a short question beforehand, does sample needs to be a single vector or could it be a data frame or matrix with the possibility to select the column sample with the values in it?

Comment: @JmO Linear search is `O(n)`. For `n = 10^12` that is prohibitive, especially when you want to do it `10^7` times. On the other hand, binary search is `O(log_2(n))`. The base 2 logarithm of 10^12 is about 40. Note that 40 steps per search rather than 10^12 is a speed-up by a factor of 25 billion. It won't take days or even hours. Just a couple of minutes should suffice.

Comment: thanks a lot both of you!! I will implement it today. For the answer above: As I have not really worked with data.table does this give me only the nearest match or every match in the tolerance range?: Consider I have an F = 154.0033 in the reference list. Now for 156.0032 in the sample there are A and F from the reference list in tolerancerange and I want to have both in the resulting list in seperate rows. Is that possible with this approach or does it only give me the nearest one?

Comment: a solution like roll="nearest" +- 2 should be enough. Is there any way to implement this? would be very very nice. Thanks a lot in advance for every help here.