# round number to a fixed interval from a vector in r

Tags: r, decimal, rounding

I have a vector like this:

```
> seq(157.5,180.5,1)
> [1] 157.5 158.5 159.5 160.5 161.5 162.5 163.5 164.5 165.5 166.5 167.5 168.5 169.5 170.5 171.5 172.5 173.5 174.5 175.5 176.5 177.5 178.5 179.5 180.5
```

l would like to round any decimal number within this range to the nearest number (floor) in this vector. For example:

```
> round(165.28)=164.5
```

Is there any idea how to do it?

Comment: Sure, but I am looking for a floor one.

Comment: Check `findInterval`

Comment: As Henrik suggests, `xx[findInterval(165.28, xx)]`

Comment: That works! Thanks to Henrik and Ryan.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Find closest value in a vector with binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133344/find-closest-value-in-a-vector-with-binary-search). In the accepted answer, you need to change the `roll` parameter.